# What is --project in dotnet ef database update for?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dotnet-cli

I have  a  solution consisting of 4 projects:

- `EntityProject` :  contains POCO classes.
- `ContextProject` : contains database context derived from `DbContext`, has a reference to `EntityProject`.
- `MigrationProject` : contains `public class Empty{}`, has a reference to `ContextProject`.
- `StartupProject` :  for example Asp.Net Core Webapi, has references to `ContextProject` and `MigrationProject`.

In `StartupProject`, I invoke `MigrationAssembly(typeof(MigrationProject.Empty).Assembly.GetName().Name)` to change the migration assembly project from the default `ContextProject` to `MigrationProject`.

If the current working directory is the solution directory, I usually do the following and it works.

- migration with
  `dotnet ef migrations add Initial --project MigrationProject --startup-project StartupProject`
  where `--project` is mandatory.
- updating database with
  `dotnet ef database update --startup-project StartupProject`
  where `--project` is omitted.

Now I am wondering why `dotnet ef database update` also has `--project` switch, what is it for? Is there an example in which `--project` is mandatory?

Any comments are always welcome!

Comment: It is just a general parameter not used by Update database https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Design/Design/Internal/MigrationsOperations.cs#L197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a general parameter not used by the Update database code path

See source here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Design/Design/Internal/MigrationsOperations.cs#L197

Comment: Sir, I cannot find the method associated with `dotnet ef database drop` in the given github. I want to check whether `--project` is also ignored for `database drop`.

Comment: Here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Design/Design/Internal/DbContextOperations.cs#L91